# Why is Lubuntu default desktop environment

Tags: desktop-environments, default, unity-greeter

So I just wanted to try things out on 14.04, so I did

```
sudo apt-get install lxde
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

When I get to the greeter, it reads

```
Lubuntu (Default)
Lubuntu Netbook
LXDE
Openbox
Ubuntu
```

Why is Lubuntu default? I don't know if its because its the last thing I installed or if its because it is in alphabetical order. I'm tempted to test this theory by installing Xubuntu and see if it becomes default. I'd like it to read Ubuntu (Default) and have the Ubuntu splash instead.

When I open lightdm.conf, there is no line "user-session" nor "greeter-session". They are missing. Is this normal and I have to add it manually?

Comment: Have you tried to just reinstall ubuntu-desktop? `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: It defaults to the last one you used. Boot into Ubuntu and then reboot. "Ubuntu" should now be the default.